# Ungroup over more than one columns in a given table

Tags: kdb

The answer provided here was supposed to work for many columns,
[how to use ungroup with multiple composite columns in kdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314493/how-to-use-ungroup-with-multiple-composite-columns-in-kdb)

But it doesn't. For cases like:

```
tb:([] x: 0 1 10; y:(1 1; 2 2 2; enlist 3); z:("kk";"ttt"; enlist "j");w:("cc";"bbbb";enlist "a")
ungroup1: {[col;tbl] @[tbl where count each tbl col;col;:;raze tbl col]}
```

This will work:

````
q)ungroup1[`y;tb]
x  y z     w     
-----------------
0  1 "kk"  "cc"  
0  1 "kk"  "cc"  
1  2 "ttt" "bbbb"
1  2 "ttt" "bbbb"
1  2 "ttt" "bbbb"
10 3 ,"j"  ,"a" 
```q

Again based on single column, 

```q
q)ungroup1[`z;tb]
x  y     z w     
-----------------
0  1 1   k "cc"  
0  1 1   k "cc"  
1  2 2 2 t "bbbb"
1  2 2 2 t "bbbb"
1  2 2 2 t "bbbb"
10 ,3    j ,"a"
````

This won't work (raises `'length`):

```
ungroup1[`y`z;tb]
```

Desired result:

```
x y z w
------------
0 1 k "cc"
0 1 k "cc"
1 2 t "bbbb"
1 2 t "bbbb"
1 2 t "bbbb"
10 3 j ,"a"
```

May I hear some input from the experts please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ungroup is implemented as `raze flip each t`, you can copy that approach but exclude (and re-join) the columns you *don't* want to be ungrouped.

```
q)raze{key[y]#flip[x _y],\:(x:(),x)#y}[`w]each tb
x  y z w
-------------
0  1 k "cc"
0  1 k "cc"
1  2 t "bbbb"
1  2 t "bbbb"
1  2 t "bbbb"
10 3 j ,"a"

q)raze{key[y]#flip[x _y],\:(x:(),x)#y}[`y`w]each tb
x  y     z w
-----------------
0  1 1   k "cc"
0  1 1   k "cc"
1  2 2 2 t "bbbb"
1  2 2 2 t "bbbb"
1  2 2 2 t "bbbb"
10 ,3    j ,"a"
```

Assumes that the columns you've chosen to ungroup are actually ungroup-able (aka have matching lengths)

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! Can this be written as a function though? just to take the column headers as parameters and table. I feel this jumped from simple to highly complex form lol. How does the [`y`w]each tb map to x and y inside the raze{}, or does it at all? what is this form, its a mix of..built-in function with query?

Comment: Yes you can make it a function with `ungroupX:{raze{key[y]#flip[x _y],\:(x:(),x)#y}[x]each y}`, called as `ungroupX[\`y\`w;tb]`. To answer your other question - the `\`y\`w` becomes `x` in the inner function while each row of `tb` becomes `y`

Comment: I think there is some mistake as in the 2nd example you provided, y and w are not ungrouped. They are rather, grouped.

Comment: and with another example.. where for instance the column y has increasing values, `tb:([] x: 0 1 10; y:(1 1; 20 40 60; enlist 3); z:("kk";"ttt"; enlist "j");w:("cc";"bbbb";enlist "a")`, it does not accept 1 column to ungroup.

Comment: Not a mistake - with this function you specify which columns you *don't* want ungrouped. So in my second example it is expected that `y` and `w` remain grouped. For your second table above the function does work to ungroup based on only one column, e.g. `ungroupX[\`x\`z\`w;tb]`. The only way it doesn't work is if you try to ungroup only `x` column which isn't ungroupable on its own. Get around it with a protected eval `.[ungroupX;(\`y\`z\`w;tb);tb]`

Comment: protected eval is for `try-catch`. The problem I have is how to ungroup the designated columns of a table, assuming the user doesnt make a mistake. I am only wondering if you gave the opposite sample to the question I asked so that I can implement. In this case, with the disparate level of experience in KDB btw you and I does not seem to enable that sort of communication. I also find [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961648/double-triple-for-loops-using-index-of-vectors-that-vary-in-length) rather hard to configure, although your inputs are valued.